# Using the value of a variable in the name of an argument

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script which will input arguments, the command would look like this:

```
command -a -b -c file -d -e
```

I would like to detect a specific argument (-b) with its specific location ($1, $2, $3)

```
#! /bin/bash
counter=0
while [ counter -lt $# ]
do
    if [ $($counter) == "-b" ]
    then
        found=$counter
    fi
    let counter+=1
done
```

The problem rises in `$($counter)`. Is there a way to use `$counter` to call the value of an argument? For instance if `counter=2`, I would like to call the value of argument `$2`. `$($counter)` doesn't work.

Comment: Use `getopts` for this. For example http://stackoverflow.com/a/14203146/1983854 can help.

Comment: ok thanks! I'll look into it, but if I want the following filename, for instance -b filename, does `getopts` also provide this function?

Comment: Yes it does.  Did you look at the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this without `getopts` (which is still recommended, though) by reworking your loop.

```
counter=1
for i in "$@"; do
  if [[ $i == -b ]]; then
      break
  fi
  ((counter+=1))
done
```

Simply iterate over the arguments directly, rather than iterating over the argument positions.

---

`bash` also does allow indirect parameter expansion, using the following syntax:

```
#! /bin/bash
counter=0
while [ counter -lt $# ]
do
    if [ ${!counter} = "-b" ]  # ${!x} uses the value of x as the parameter name
    then
        found=$counter
    fi
    let counter+=1
done
```

Comment: Don't use `==` with single-bracket notation, `bash` accepts it but it's not POSIX-conforming and other shells choke on it. +1 for the rest!

Comment: Non-POSIX shells will probably choke on `${!counter}` anyway :) But you are correct in general.